# Any way to prevent monsters without light in Hexxit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-hexxit

In MineCraft Hexxit you have these interesting ore bushes. They require very low light to grow. I've made a room that is dark enough, but this of course also means the room will be full of monsters after a while. Turning the light on will prevent the bushes from growing.

Is there any way to prevent monsters from spawning in a room without using light?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mobs will not spawn on half-slabs, simply place half-slabs on the floor.

Comment: Are they still considered half-slabs if they are "double"?

Comment: @Svish No, they become normal blocks when double. You need to place the half slab on the lower part of another block. You'll be able to tell if you got it right if you can't place a torch on it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use any transparent block for the floor, or water. Monsters can not spawn there.

Surround your bushes floor with cristal or water. Since I didn't tried the Hexxit mod, I don't know if the bush block will prevent monsters for spawning there, but a least you will minimize the spawning area.

See [the MinecraftWiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Passive) to know the exact blocks that prevent mob spawning.